# Check database if an item has been already inserted with ROOM and RXJava

Tags: android, rx-java, android-room

I am a newbie with ROOM, RXJava and Android.

In an Android application test a REST service retrieves a list of users. This list must be revised if the user already exists. If the user does not exist then the user is inserted into the database. If the user already exists then the user is not inserted.

In Activity verification is as following:

```
UserRepository repo = new UserRepository(LoadingActivity.this);

    for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++){
                            
         if (!repo.existsUser(list.get(i))){
               repo.insert(list.get(i));
          }
    }
```

El UserDao consiste en lo siguiente:

```
@Query("select count(*) from users where name = :userName and email = :userEmail")
Single<Long> existsUser(int userName , String userEmail);
```

El UserRepository contiene lo siguiente:

```
private AppDatabase db;

public UserRepository(Context context){
    this.db  = AppDatabase.getDatabase(context);
}

public boolean existsUser(User item){

    final boolean[] existe = {false};

    db.userDao().existsUser(item.getName(), item.getEmail())
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .subscribe(query -> existe[0] = query > 0);

    return existe[0];
}

public void insert(User user){
    db.userDao().insert(user)
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.computation())
            .subscribe(new CompletableObserver() {
                @Override
                public void onSubscribe(Disposable d) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onComplete() {

                }

                @Override
                public void onError(Throwable e) {

                }
            });
}
```

It is supposed that `existe[0]` should be assigned true value when trying to insert an old user. However `existe[0] = query > 0` always follows return sentence so this way does not work.

Is it possible that RXJava returns a boolean or any value? Is there any other approach to make what I'm trying?

I would like to avoid dao rule `@Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.IGNORE)` for considering data retrieved has not primary key

Answer (score 0):

Your code has a lot of different sort of problems.

First of all, you should understand that use Activity's context to create database - extremely bad idea. You should use application context instead.

Also you try to use imperative programming style with reactive programming here:

```
if (!repo.existsUser(list.get(i))){
    repo.insert(list.get(i));
}
```

I think you need to research reactive programming and room framework more deeper before you ask some questions about it.

As for your question - You should avoid db entities without primary key.
And the only thing that you should do here to solve your problem - use `@Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.IGNORE)`  and signature of your insert fun should be something like this `fun insertIfNotExists(user: User): Completable` in Kotlin or `Completable insertIfNotExists(User user)` if you use Java

Comment: You are right about primary key so retreaving IDs and using Room- Dao onConflict  signatures makes it easier to manage data (though that was the way that service provides data... don't know why). I was blind planning logic to retrieve a boolean value around a query so using Transaction Dao signature would be a better choice if I had decided that way. Thanks about application/activity context suggestion!! :)